# How to backup database to comply with UK data protection act?

Tags: compliance, legal, backup

Charity has a server in their office onto which they backup a database with sensitive information. They want to get rid of this server.

Is there a cost effective solution that would allow them to comply with UK Data Protection Act?

Currently I think about encrypted version stored at Dropbox.

Answer (score 8):

Dropbox is compliant with the Data Protection Act, the main worry is point 8 of the Act:

> Personal data shall not be transferred to a country or territory
>   outside the European Economic Area unless that country or territory
>   ensures an adequate level of protection for the rights and freedoms of
>   data subjects in relation to the processing of personal data.

If a company is outside the EU and in the USA then there is a 'Safe Harbor' list maintained of companies that fulfil the the level of protection clause.

Here's a blog post from Dropbox saying they are now Safe Harbor certified and a link to the Safe Harbor site so you can check for yourself, might also be worth checking for other companies you're considering.

Dropbox Blog: http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=972

Safe Harbor List: http://safeharbor.export.gov/list.aspx